# Isekai manga where two high schoolers are transported to a post apocalyptic world overrun with beasts

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, manga, isekai

Does anyone know this isekai where the MC is a high schooler transported with a classmate to a post-apocalyptic world overrun by beasts.

These beasts attack humans and the MC even though being very weak has the ability to control them. If I remember correctly the beasts attack people because they have been ordered to do so by the main antagonist who can also control these beasts.

However, this antagonist has better control over them compared to the MC and I think he was also teleported to this world like the MC years before.

This is quite an old manga since I read it like 15 years ago, but it just popped into my head and I hope someone would know about it.

Comment: This is quite a brief description, can you remember anything else? How they are transported? How the main character has the ability to control them? What’s special about them? Why the beasts overran the world? What happened to make it post apocalyptic? What happens when they’re transported back? When you read this? If you remember anything else you can [edit] the details into your post.